# Parsing txt file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I want to parse a .txt file using batch script.

this is how my txt file looks like (This is just an example, it is basically much larger than that but the structure is the same):

> ```
> <job><name>jj-Aggregator-Detached-Tests</name></job><job><name>j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test</name></job><job><name>j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test-POC</name></job><job><name>j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test-POC-RunTests</name></job><job><name>j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test-TestRepo</name></job><job><name>j-Aggregator-Regression-Conditional</name></job>
> ```

I want to get all the job names in to a parameters,
so the delimeter will be "

```
<job><name>
```

"
I tried this:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=<job><name>" %%a in "MyFile.txt" do for /f "delims=name" %%c in ("%%~b") do echo %%c
```

But it doesn't get me any output.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it all one line or is each <job> element on a new line?

Answer (score 0):

This solves your question using the data you provided: put the line in `file.txt`

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=3,8,13,18,23 delims=<>" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e
)
pause
```

Comment: 2 things about this script: 1.) it gives me wrong output "name,name,name,name,name"  2.) my text file is much larger than what I post here So I need something that can handle much more data and not specify the tokens.

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan  1) The script gives me what you asked for with the data you provided.  2) If you want a script that performs a task and you don't give accurate details - then you are likely to get a script that doesn't work - because it isn't written to handle your different data.

Comment: You are right,
I just wanted to give an example file so people could see the basic structure of the file but I forgot to mention that it is only a sample and that the actual file is much larger.

Comment: Yes, this solution outputs the following for me: `jj-Aggregator-Detached-Tests,j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test,j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test-POC,j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test-POC-RunTests,j-Aggregator-Nightly-Test-TestRepo`